# Empty query result in Kylin Derived dimension

Tags: hadoop, hive, kylin

I’m using Apache Kylin, version: `apache-kylin-2.6.2-bin-hadoop3`/

In Insight query, I find the derived dimension column always returns an empty result. But using the same SQL in Hive shows that the column has data.

Here is the SQL I'm trying:

```sql
SELECT trans.user_id, user.tag1
FROM trans
INNER JOIN user ON trans.user_id = user.id;
```

...where `user.tag1` is the derived dimension, which is empty.

If I only change dimension type from `derived` to `normal` and rebuild the cube, there's no such problem.

What's even more strange is, if I try another lookup table, the result shows that some rows have a value and some don't. I cannot find the difference between these correlations, and everything is fine in Hive query.

What might the problem be?